# about orthogonal catastrophe

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body

I am reading Wen's book, QFT of many-body systems ( @Xiao-Gang Wen ). I am a little confused about the orthogonal catastrophe introduced in Chap.5. Below Eq.(5.1.6), it is stated that ``the influence of the core electron on the *conduction electron* Green's function is not important...''.

If I understand correctly,  it is exactly the (almost) vanishing overlap between the initial and final state wavefunctions of the *conduction electrons* that causes the orthogonal catastrophe. Why does the asumption that ``the influence of the core electron on the *conduction electron* Green's function is not important'' works?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try searhcing for "Anderson orthogonality catastrophy"

Comment: I cannot find a satisfactory answer by this search. Actually I know the basic idea of orthogonal catastrophe. What I don't understand is the seemingly different approach in Wen's book, which seems to work anyway.  @Slaviks